# Leaflet JS TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of null

Tags: angular, leaflet, mapbox

I'm creating map on Leaflet JS + Mapbox. Trying to highlight my regions visually. I have code, which paint over my regions by my geoJSON, which i created. But when I wrote code for highlighting my regions on mousover, i have an TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of null.

My Code

Trying to refactor my code with leaflet doc.

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {MapService} from '../../src/app/core/shared/services/map.service'

import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-routing-machine';
import 'leaflet-providers';
import {style} from "@angular/animations";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('mapWrapper')
  mapWrapper: ElementRef;

  zoom = 6;

  /* Regions */
  regionsGeoJsonSubscription$: Subscription;
  regionsGeoJson: any;


  constructor(private mapService: MapService) {
  }

  title = 'leaflet-routing-sample';

  private map: L.Map = null;
  private geojson = null;


  style(featurecollection) {
    return {
      fillColor: '#99d8c9' ,
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1,
      color: 'white',
      dashArray: '3',
      fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.regionsGeoJsonSubscription$ = this.mapService.getRegionsGeoJson()
      .subscribe(regionsGeoJson => {
          this.regionsGeoJson = regionsGeoJson;
          //this.regionsGeoJsonLoaded = Object.keys(this.regionsGeoJson).length > 0;
          //this.statisticsEnabled = true;
        this.map = L.map('map')
          .setView([55.744100, 37.627027], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=mytoken', {
          id: 'mapbox.light',
          attribution: null
        }).addTo(this.map)

        L.geoJson(this.regionsGeoJson, {style: this.style}).addTo(this.map);
        }
      );

    function highlightFeature(e) {
      this.layer = e.target;

      this.layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
      });

      if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        this.layer.bringToFront();
      }
    }

    function resetHighlight(e) {
      this.geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    }

    function zoomToFeature(e) {
      this.map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    }



    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
      this.layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
      });
    }

    this.geojson = L.geoJson(this.regionsGeoJson, {
      style: style,
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(this.map);

  }

}
```

[My map and DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMtsf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before `onEachFeature` you have:

```
this.geojson = L.geoJson(this.regionsGeoJson, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(this.map);
```

On this moment, this map is not initialized and is null and when you call `addTo` method it's internaly do `map.addLayer(this);`

**EDIT :**

You missed something in your `onEachFeature` function :

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
    });
}
```

it's `layer.on` not `this.layer.on` because you don't have any variable layer in your current class, it's the layer variable that is passed into the function.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, i tried it earlier, but in that case we'll have TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined.

Comment: or you have to bind the function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Julien Metral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5300496/julien-metral), he's direct me to my solution. So, here it is:

```
ngOnInit() {

this.regionsGeoJsonSubscription$ = this.mapService.getRegionsGeoJson()
  .subscribe(regionsGeoJson => {
      this.regionsGeoJson = regionsGeoJson;
    this.map = L.map('map')
      .setView([55.744100, 37.627027], 6);

    function highlightFeature(e) {

      const layer = e.target;

      layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
      });

      if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
      }
    }

    function resetHighlight(e) {
      this.geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    }

    function zoomToFeature(e) {
      this.map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    }


    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
      layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
      });
    }

    this.geojson = L.geoJson(this.regionsGeoJson, {
      style: this.style,
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(this.map);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=mytoken', {
      id: 'mapbox.light',
      attribution: null
    }).addTo(this.map)

    }
  );
}
```